# .Net Standard 2.0 SQLite.Core Assembly not found in Unit Test

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-standard

I have been developing a .Net Standard library that makes a lot of API calls and as well some of those API calls need to be cross-referenced with a SQLite database the API provides. I am developing a Unit Test project alongside the .Net Standard library to test that everything is working, as well having a Unit Test project grow with the library is great. I wrote a block of code that I was hoping would allow me easy access to that SQLite DB however, I am getting

> Assembly not found errors: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.109.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I went ahead and installed the nugets packages

- SQLite
- System.Data.SQLite
- System.Data.SQLite.Core

into my .Net Standard library and my Unit Test project.

I get my error in the Unit Test after trying to create a new instance of this class.

My Data Access Class:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace D2DataAccess.SqLite
{
    public class SQLiteDestinyEngine
    {
        private readonly SQLiteConnection Connection;

        public SQLiteDestinyEngine(FileInfo LocalPath)
        {
            var builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = LocalPath.FullName };
            Connection = new SQLiteConnection(builder.ToString());
        }

        public async Task<Dictionary<long, T>> GetDetailedInformationFromHash<T>(string TableName, params long[] itemHashes)
        {
            return await await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                var dataSet = new Dictionary<long, T>();
                var query = $"select id, json from '{TableName}' where id in (@hashes)";
                using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(query, Connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hashes", itemHashes);
                    var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        dataSet.Add(reader.GetInt64(0), JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(reader.GetString(1)));
                    }
                }
                return dataSet;
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```